# Gene Network Topological Overlap Python

Tags: python, networkx

In a complex gene network how can we find a topological overlap.

Input data as follows

```
code  code weight

3423 3455   3453
2344 2353   45
3432 3453   456
3235 4566   34532
2345 8687   356
2466 6467   3567
3423 2344   564
3455 2353   4564
3432 3423   456
```

The node columns are col[0] and col[1] and the time spent connected is col[2]

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("USC_Test.txt")
col = []
edge_list = zip[col[0],col[1]]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
components = nx.connected_components(G)

print components
```

Error

```
edge_list = zip[col[0],col[1]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3186

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must confess that I wasn't familiar with the term *topological overlap* so I had to look it up:

> A pair of nodes in a network is said to have high topological overlap if they are both strongly connected to the same group of nodes. ([Source](http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/MTOM/))

NetworkX doesn't seem to have a builtin method which lets you find pairs of nodes with topological overlap but it can easily find strongly connected components. For example:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx
In [2]: edge_list = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 4), (5, 6)]
In [3]: G = nx.DiGraph()
In [4]: G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
In [5]: components = nx.strongly_connected_components(G)
In [6]: components
Out[6]: [[1, 3, 2], [4], [6], [5]]
```

If you have an undirected graph you can use `nx.connected_components` instead.

Now you have components, it is straightforward to find all lists of pairs with toplogical overlap. For example, generate all pairs of nodes from lists in `components`:

```
In [7]: from itertools import combinations
In [8]: top_overlap = [list(combinations(c, 2)) for c in components if len(c) > 1]
In [9]: top_overlap = [item for sublist in top_overlap for item in sublist]
In [10]: top_overlap
Out[10]: [(1, 3), (1, 2), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much ..I shall try this execution with the real data.

Comment: This seems to be the fine way but i would need some more suggestion help in including the weights in them like in the output: [[1, 3, 2], [4], [6], [5]] But i was hoping for something like this: [[1,3,2,2453]] the three nodes those strongly connected and also the total time they are connected to each other.

Comment: I am getting errors when i am trying to load the nodes from a file. Please could you suggest anything in that case.

Comment: @SitzBlogz: looking at your edit, if `col[0]` and `col[1]` are both lists containing the nodes, you can write `edge_list = zip(col[0], col[1])` and continue (that's where the NetworkX error is probably coming from).

Comment: it shows a new error now. I also tried `edge_list = zip[(col[0], col[1])]` and still its the same.

Comment: Ah... If it's an issue with reading data from a file, it might be best to post the problem as a new question showing what you're doing and what Python says the error is. That'll probably help to get the root of the problem more quickly.