# Node Pair Occrance with Weight Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, graph, nodes

I have to calculate the number times and the percentage of the node pairs occur in a series of data. I am very well able to calculate this but, the problem comes when i have also include the third parameter i.e. the time in seconds. These node pairs contact each other and spend some time connected and that time is in seconds. The total of time in seconds to the corresponding node pairs is also supposed to be calculated.

Eg: Input

```
    Node  Node Time
     A     B    455
     A     B    456
     A     B    463
     A     C    4
     A     C    675
     C     B    64
     C     B    78
     C     B    579
```

The output that i am getting is which is  correct so far.

```
Node   Node   paircount pairpercentage
   A       B      3       37.5
   A       C      2       25
   C       B      3       37.5
```

The output i am supposed to get get is

```
Node Node Paircount pairpercentage  Time
A     B      3       37.5            1374
A     C      2       25               679
C     B      3       37.5             721
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

# get number of occurences for the first two columns
with open('Inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    #f.readline() # discard the header line
    for numlines, line in enumerate(f,1):
        line = line.strip().split()
        c = line[0], line[1]
        d[c] += 1

# compute 100*(occurences/numlines) for each key in d
d = {k:(v, 100*float(v)/numlines) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
 for k in d:
    #print k, d[k]
    outfile.write("%s %s\n" % (k, d[k]))
```

Note: The above code works perfectly for the half that i have mentioned i need some help for the remaining half dealing with time addition with respect to node pairs.

InputFile

```
5454 5070 2755.0
5070 4391 2935.0
1158 305  1.0
5045 3140 48767.0
4921 3140 58405.0
5372 2684 460.0
1885 1158 351.0
1349 1174 6375.0
1980 1174 650.0
1980 1349 650.0
4821 2684 469.0
4821 937  459.0
2684 937  318.0
1980 606  390.0
1349 606  750.0
1174 606  750.0
5045 3545 8133.0
4921 3545 8133.0
3545 3140 8133.0
5045 4243 14863.0
4921 4243 14863.0
4243 3545 8013.0
4243 3140 14863.0
4821 4376 5471.0
4376 937  136.0
2613 968  435.0
5372 937  83.0
```

Code2:  With the help from answer below, i can calculate the paircount and also the time but i am not able to get the percentage now. I am also looking for some output cleaning.

```
from collections import defaultdict
paircount = defaultdict(int)
pairtime = defaultdict(float)
pairper = defaultdict(float)

#get number of pair occurrences and total time 
with open('USC_Test.txt', 'r') as f:
  with open('pair.txt', 'w') as o:
    numline = 0
    for line in f:
        numline += 1
            line = line.split()
        pair = line[0], line[1]
        paircount[pair] += 1
        pairtime[pair] += float(line[2])
        pairper = float(paircount/line)*100      

print "%s\n" % paircount
print "%s\n" % pairtime
print "%s\n" % pairper
```

Output: only when  `pairper = float(paircount/line)*100` is commented else it gives an error as given below.

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('1349', '606'): 1, ('2684', '937'): 1,
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {('1349', '606'): 750.0, ('2684', '937'): 318.0,
```

But when `pairper = float(paircount/line)*100` is not in comment

Error:  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'collections.defaultdict' and 'list'`

Expected Output is with no text as `defaultdict(<type 'int'>, or deafultdict(<type 'float'>` but only

```
node node paircount pairper   pairtime
1349 606     1      somevalue  750.0
2684 937     1      somevalue  318.0
```

Any suggestion appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another `defaultdict` to sum the times into. (EDIT: now with the additional changes.)

```
from collections import defaultdict
paircount = defaultdict(int)
pairtime = defaultdict(float)

with open('Inputfile.txt') as f:
    numlines = 0
    for line in f:
        numlines += 1
        line = line.split()
        pair = line[0], line[1]
        paircount[pair] += 1
        pairtime[pair] += float(line[2])

pairper = dict((pair, c * 100.0 / numlines) for (pair, c) in paircount.iteritems())
for pair, c in paircount.iteritems():
    print pair[0], pair[1], c, pairper[pair], pairtime[pair]
```

I also fixed the off-by-one error involving `numlines`, removed the redundant `.strip()`, and renamed some variables for clarity.

Comment: @Devid This is what i am exactly looking for. Thanks!! Can ask for another query. A similar question that i have posed. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459908/gene-network-topological-overlap-python/25461445#25461445)

Comment: I am getting error when i am trying to calculate the percentage of occurrence `paircount[pair] = {k:(v, 100*float(v)/line) for k,v in paircount[pair].iteritems()}` Error `'int' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` And also I can either print the `paircount` or the `pairtime` but not both.

Comment: @SitzBlogz If you're using Python 3, then they renamed `iteritems()` to plain old `items()`, and the `print` syntax is different.

Comment: I have edited the main question with exact changes and i am using python 2.7.3

Comment: @SitzBlogz I edited in the fix for the comprehension and how to print the output more nicely. If you want the columns justified, you should ask another question.

Comment: Thanks Again :) everything perfect now.